# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two classes: class A and class B. Class A makes a number and passes it to class B.

When I define class A in class B, Flash throws a `TypeError`:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

It's a common error in Flash.

I have two functions in class A:

Class A:

```
public function ClassAConstractor():void{
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , OnMouseDown );
  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , OnMouseUp);
}
```

Class B:

```
mmm = new ClassAConstractor(); // << when i want define class a in b
```

When I remove those two lines in the constructor function of class A, the problem is solved, but I need those two lines.

This problem shows when I define class A in class B. When I don’t any define class A in class B, there is no problem; it works well.

I know Flash throws error for STAGE, but I don’t know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you're attempting to access the stage before it's available.  use an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event.

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

//Class
public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
    //Constructor
    public function MyClass()
        {
        //trace(stage.stageWidth);
        //too early to call the stage, unless MyClass is the Document Class

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

    //Initialization
    private function init(evt:Event):void
        {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        trace(stage.stageWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped me with a similar issue I was having with Error: #1009.  I am loading external .swf into my main one and this error kept getting thrown whenever the loaded .swf had a document class.  Thanx